# Rendering Dynamic form controls in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to generate dynamic form controls, where form variables and their respective data types are stored in MySql DB table. This the code I am using to render the master variables on the form. But the options I have tried have some or the other issue. The code goes as:

Labels.cs

```
public partial class Labels
{
   public int Label_Id { get; set; }
   public string Label_Name { get; set; }
   public string Form_Element_Type { get; set; }
}

public partial class Observation
{
   public int Observation_Id {get; set;}
   public int Employee_Id {get; set;}
   public int Label_Id {get; set;}
   public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

Model Class

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
   public Dictionary<string, string> ObsDictionay { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
Public class EmployeeController
{
    Public ActionResult ProcessEmployee ()
{
      List<MasterLabel> masterLabels = new List<MasterLabel>();
                IMasterLabel masterLabelManager = new MasterLabelsManager();
                masterLabels = masterLabelManager.GetAll();
                model.MasterLabels = masterLabels;  

    IObservation obsManager = new ObservationManager();
                List<Observation> obsList = new List<Observation>();
                obsList = obsManager.GetAllByPatientId(id);
                Dictionary<string, string> ObsDictionay = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                foreach (var label in masterLabels)
                {
                    int flag = 0;
                    if (obsList.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var obs in obsList)
                        {
                            if (label.Label_Id == obs.Label_Id)
                            {
                                ObsDictionay.Add(label.Label_Id.ToString(), obs.Value);
                                flag = 1;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        if (flag == 0)
                        {
                            ObsDictionay.Add(label.Master_Label_Id.ToString(), null);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ObsDictionay.Add(label.Master_Label_Id.ToString(), null);
                    }

                }

                model.ObsDictionay = ObsDictionay;


}

}
```

Views --- Options that I have already tried and are not fulfilling the requirement

**OPTION 1:**

```
<input class="control-label" type="@item.Form_Element_Type" id="@item.Master_Label_Id" name="@item.Master_Label_Id "  value= @Model.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()]">
```

**This option retuning null ObsDictionay to [HttpPost] method in controller**

**OPTION 2:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()])
```

**This option retuning ObsDictionay to [HttpPost] method in controller with all the values but rendering textbox for all variables**

**OPTION 3:**

```
@if (item.Form_Element_Type == "checkbox")
{
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()] == "Y"? true : false)
}
else if(item.Form_Element_Type == "textbox")
{
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()])                                        
 }
```

**ERROR : System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions, while rendering checkbox.**

Can someone help me in this.

Comment: I have used dynamic form in one of the projects and also written [blog](http://blogs.quovantis.com/dynamic-models-for-mvc-view/). I found Expando object and dynamically typed view more suitable

Comment: Option 1 Would not work because model binding is done by name of property. Instead of giving name like "@item.Master_Label_Id " try giving name of control like "@item.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()]"

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Should it be `<input class="control-label" type="@item.Form_Element_Type" id="@item.Master_Label_Id" name="@item.Master_Label_Name "  value= @Model.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()]">`

I don't know why you have `@item.Master_Label_Id` instead of `@item.Label_Id` either.

**Option 2**

The issue is that `@Html.EditorFor` depends on property type - since all you fields are `string`, textbox is the chosen input. You would have to diverse field types to get it working(maybe by passing `object` and typecasting it to desired type safely).

**Option 3**

I don't think that `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()] == "Y"? true : false)` is valid cause as I remember you have to pass expression as first parameter. Change it to `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()], new { Value = Model.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()] == "Y" ? true : false)`

Comment: Option 3 --@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()], new { Value = Model.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()] == "Y" ? true : false)

x => x.ObsDictionay[item.Label_Id.ToString()] is giving error "Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool"...........

any help?/

Comment: @user1414935 - can you post code of action where you bind input values to model properties?

Comment: Plz refer to the controller code "EmployeeController" above

And the HttpPost Method

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessEmployee (EmployeeModel model, FormCollection collection)
{
            
            return View();
}

On clicking the submit button the code hits the HttpPost Method but model in parameter contains obsDictionary object as null